# Перечисление и обобщающее слово

Tags: синтаксис

Здравствуйте, в предложении для перечисления "переезды, путешествия и т. д." обобщающим словом будет "состояния" или "символами"?

> Как правило, близкий конец бывает отмечен символами нового рождения,
>   которые сопровождают переходные состояния и в обычной жизни: переезды,
>   путешествия и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

***Переходные состояния*** ―  переезды, путешествия и т. д., соответственно, это и есть обобщающее слово.